# how to configure a default (or common) virtualhost for non-ssl domains when ssl domains exist?

Tags: ssl, virtualhost, apache-2.4

I have several domains running on the same (physical) server under Apache 2.4 web server.

Some of these domains support secure connections (over the standard HTTPS protocol).
For them I configured the relevant `<VirtualHost *:443>` directives that turn on the ssl engine, point to the certificate, and so forth. And everything works as expected for them.

But I found (and that's explained in the docs) that when no matching `<VirtualHost *:443>` can be found for a request, then a fallback logic kicks in that could (and in fact does) select another domain configuration.

What I'm getting is that if I try to connect through HTTPS to a domain that has no SSL configured, I get the certificate of another domain.

Having more than one hundred configured domains on that web server, is there a "catch all" configuration that lets me redirect all HTTPS connections to HTTP on the same domain for those domains that have no explicit `<VirtualHost *:443>` configuration?

Comment: If I'm understanding [this question and its answers](http://serverfault.com/q/555367/242122), that's not possible, right?